# Nested or correlated subquery SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, correlated-subquery, relational-algebra

I have the following relational algebra task, which I need to convert into a SQL query, compatible with Microsoft SQL server:

The relevant tables are below:

**Raw_Materials_t**: material_ID, material_description,

**Supplies_t**: Vendor_ID, Material_ID, Unit_Price

**Vendor_t**: Vendor_ID, Vendor_Name

```
SELECT DISTINCT V.Vendor_ID
FROM Raw_Materials_t R, Supplies_t S, Vendor_t V
WHERE R.Material_description = 'walnut'
  AND S.Unit_price < 14
  AND R.Unit_price < 14
  AND V.Vendor_ID = S.Vendor_ID
```

I've been told that my query does produce the correct result, but it does not explicitly use the ordered relational algebra steps. So what I need to do is:

1. (Natural?) join Raw_Materials_t on Supplies_t selecting only rows where it's true that material_description is walnut and unit_price is less than $14
2. Take these results, project only the Vendor_ID column (discarding other columns)
3. Join this column on Vendor_t
4. Project only the Vendor_Name column from the above results.

Is this is a nested subquery or a correlated subquery? I'm not familiar with either and unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Your last two qs sound like you want some answer in RA. But your opening sentence says "convert into a SQL query". You give an SQL query. So I don't understand what more you want. 'correlated subquery' is a term that only applies in SQL, and there isn't one in the SQL you give. The RA is an algebra, which means an RA query typically has nesting of operator invocations. Because it's an algebra, it's not usual to talk about 'nested subquery' any more than you would talk about 'nested arithmetic expression'. Again, 'nested subquery' is more a term from SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have a join condition between Material and anything else.

This is the complete query, which is just simple joins, no correlated queries or subqueries:

```
SELECT distinct V.Vendor_ID 
FROM Raw_Materials_t R
join Supplies_t S on S.Material_ID=R.Material_ID
join Vendor_t V on V.Vendor_ID=S.Vendor_ID
WHERE R.Material_description = 'walnut' AND S.Unit_price < 14
```